# How to split content and append in HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="postFull">
        <!-- Capa -->
        <h1>testando conteúdo</h1>
        <p>testando conteudo</p>

        <hr>

        <!-- Conteúdo 1 -->
        <h2>testando conteudo com h2 - 1</h2>
        <p>testando conteudo com p para h2 - 2</p>

        <hr>

        <!-- Conteúdo 2 -->
        <h2>testando conteudo com h2 - 1</h2>
        <p>testando conteudo com p para h2 - 2</p>

        <br><br>
    </div>
```

How to split the content after each *< hr >* tag and append each block of splited content in another HTML tag, like this:

```
<article id="splitContent">
    ... input each block of content here (could be anothers articles)
</article>
```

Thanks for help. The best!

Comment: do you me show content side by side?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph sorry, what's content?

Comment: Given that large block of HTML code, can you show us *exactly* what the result would be?

Comment: i meant, what is splited content mean? is it showing the `article` side by side?

Comment: yes @NidhinJoseph!

Comment: @JackBashford I have this picture - http://prntscr.com/o8tb54 . You cant test on this link - http://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/jquery

Comment: What's the context?

If you need to do it only this time and never again in the future, a _quick and dirty_ solution would be the best.

If you need to do it manually many times, we can help you automate the task. 

If this needs to be executed on the user's page, it requires a whole different approach. 

What's the context? Why are you asking this question?

Comment: Adriano -  I want to split this content with javascript, that is, move the content inside postFull tag to SplitContent tag. I Think that i can store the content inside postFull in javascript Object and split the content between each < HR > in another Tag (splitContent).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout) to achieve this

```js
(function() {
  let articles = [{
    title: 'testando conteudo com h2 - 1',
    content: 'testando conteudo com p para h2 - 1'
  }, {
    title: 'testando conteudo com h2 - 2',
    content: 'testando conteudo com p para h2 - 2'
  }];
  let splitContent = document.getElementById('splitContent');

  articles.forEach(e => {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = `
       <article>
        <h2>${e.title}</h2>
        <p>${e.content}</p>
      </article>
      `;
    splitContent.append(div);
  });
})();
```

```css
#splitContent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

article {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="postFull">
  <!-- Capa -->
  <h1>testando conteúdo</h1>
  <p>testando conteudo</p>

  <hr>

  <div id="splitContent"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: I want to split this content with javascript, that is, move the content inside postFull tag to SplitContent tag. I Think that i can store the content inside postFull in javascript Object and split the content between each < HR > in another Tag (splitContent).

Comment: I am sorry friend, but I cannot quite understand your issue. Do you mean that the article content comes from a JS object and you need to insert it to `splitContent` dynamically?

Comment: Yes! Basically, I have the content of a page that divides each section by an hr tag, as in the example I submitted.

I need to get these sections that are between each HR block and then treat the elements to appear in another tag in isolation, creating an article item for each block I've isolated.

Comment: @HitchLeonardo I have edited the code to take the data from a list and insert it dynamically. Hope this is what you are after, thanks :)